# Dynamic update of UI data

Tags: web-applications

I am working on a web application. On server side we are using Restful service,EJB and JPA. On client side we are using extension js. My concern is that suppose an user is interacting with UI, and a table is populated with data fetched from server. Meanwhile another user has modified the server data,meaning that first user is seeing stale data and hence his action wont be in line with current state of server data.

How can we avoid such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how to go about this, but WebSockets may be helpful for your situation. A similar question was asked here: [how to update ui lively without refreshing page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/296624/how-to-update-ui-lively-without-refreshing-page)

FlorianF's answer can get you headed in the right direction

A little more WebSocket info: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html

Best of luck!